# Where can I find ready to use windows scripts that used robocopy?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2003, backup, robocopy, vss

We are installing the Windows Resource Kit, and that installs RoboCopy.  We want to have access to a few windows scripts that uses RoboCopy so we can start from those to build something else.  Any ideas on where I can find a few samples?

NOTE 1:

A bit of information. Every time we try to copy D drive to E drive (new drive) we get an error that says:

> ERROR 32 (0x000000020) Copying File d:\pagefile.sys The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.  Waiting 30 seconds.

Just to help figure it out.

Comment: Are you looking for the /XF parameter to exclude pagefile.sys, or are you trying to copy the page file. I think the page file will always be in use while the system is running. I don't think you would need to copy it though.

Answer (score 5):

I used Robocopy to synchronize website content across 9 web servers.  Here's a sample of the batch file that ran robocopy.exe.  This batch file was scheduled to run every 5 or 10 minutes or could be run manually to push changes immediately.

```
robocopy.exe d:\inetpub\wwwroot\ \\webserver1\d$\inetpub\wwwroot\ *.* /E /PURGE /SEC /NP /NJH /NJS /XF keepalive_*.* /XD trigger /XD "D:\inetpub\wwwroot\Long Path Name" /R:5 /COPYALL /LOG:copy_to_webserver1.log
```

The previous command will copy the content of d:\inetpub\wwwroot and push it to the remote server's d:\inetpub\wwwroot.

/E = copies all subdirectories including empty ones
/PURGE = deletes destination files/folders that no longer exist in the source
/SEC = copies the security permissions (ACL) of the files to the destination location
/NP = turns off the copy progress bar; DEFINITELY do this if you are logging the results
/NJH = don't log the job header
/NJS = don't log the job summary
/XF = exclude copying specific files (e.g. keepalive_*.*)
/XD = exclude copying specific folders (e.g. trigger)
/R = specifies number of times to retry if the copy fails (e.g. 5)
/COPYALL = copies everything: data, attributes, timestamps, security, ownership and auditing information; overkill really since I specified /SEC
/LOG = log results to the specified log file (e.g. copy_to_webserver1.log)

I hope that gets you started on Robocopy.  I found it to be a highly reliable and very robust solution for keeping our content in sync.

Comment: does you still use robocopy script ? now, any alternative better than robocopy ?

Comment: Yes, I'm still using it.  It's easy to use and is already there.  No additional install.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have any scripts, but the built-in documentation is really easy to understand and very useful.

```
robocopy /? | more
```

Comment: Don't forget "robocopy /??? | more " to get the full documentation for all the switches.

Answer (score 0):

Its really so simple that most just do their own from scratch. I have never seen any "code samples", as its basically just a matter of from where, to where with some parameters thrown in... but have a look at the different robocopy GUIs out there (just google it), most of them will show you the generated command.

Comment: Thanks, the basic use of robocopy itself is simple, I agree.  I was hoping to see something for exception handling and other fault tolerance on the scripts itself.  Basically i am looking to have a schedule job copy one drive to another drive.

Comment: This sort of stuff is pretty much handled internally in Robocopy, for example it will auto-retry files by default ad infinitum if they are locked. The parameters to Robocopy are how you control this behaviour, rather than by building any scripting voodoo.

Answer (score 0):

So , looking at your comment to Trondh, I have several RoboCopy scripts that are scheduled, however the way this is accomplished (by me anyway) is via scheduled task. So as an example, I have a RoboCopy Script that copies files from drive X: to Drive Y: using whatever parameters I specify. I then create a scheduled task to run this script at a specified interval, and if I am worried about monitoring this script, I can create a second step to the task that emails myself the output log if I want to review it regularly.

Comment: Thanks Charles.  Do you use the /mir option for your solution?

Comment: yes depending on the job. We have several that do not due to legacy data however.

Comment: any samples (options, parameters )  ***RoboCopy scripts*** ? anyways, can you create a **scheduled task** _programmatically_ ?

Answer (score 0):

Start small, just copying a single folder from point a to point b.  Be sure to include the /L switch and the /LOG switch.  The /L switch just lists the files it would have copied and the /Log will create a log so you can verify what you want copied.  From there you just increase the complexity.  For an example script:

robocopy "C:\test_source" "\server01\C$\test_destination" /L /V /E /LOG:"c:\test_robocopy.log" /R:10 /W:30

Answer (score 0):

To solve the second problem, (the locked file error and subsequent wait), use the switches `/r`, `/w` and `/reg`, for example:

```
robocopy D:\ E:\ /r:1 /w:1 /reg
```

This means **r**etry one time only after **w**aiting one second and make these settings default in the **reg**istry.

Answer (score 0):

The linked [script](http://blogs.msdn.com/adioltean/archive/2005/01/05/346793.aspx) is a template that can used to copy open files. You can just change the copy command in the script to robocopy and you will be able to robocopy open files.